# Running function a few times but why am I only seeing output being returned once?

Tags: javascript

I'm running the following code but I only see the output of the function being returned once which I've also added at the bottom, instead of 3 statements being printed out, I can't see why. I am a newbie to learning JavaScript by the way:

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours) {
 if (numHours >= 8 ) {
     return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
 }
 else {
     return "Get some more shut eye!";
 }
};

sleepCheck(10);
sleepCheck(5);
sleepCheck(9);
"You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!"
```

Comment: use `console.log(sleepCheck(n))`

Comment: How do you run your code?

Comment: @redu thanks I tried that already, maybe I should have added it to the question.

Comment: @PatrykPerduta just in the chrome console.

Comment: Can I ask why this was downvoted please, might help me in future with my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in fact not printing anything to console, the console will take the last function's return value and print that, but there is nothing to be output end to console any other way.

You need to put `console.log()` somewhere to make it work or `document.write()`

Comment: Thanks I'll mark this as the best answer because I didn't realise that the console only prints the last functions return value, I was mixing the return with console.log and couldn't figure out what was happening, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Returning something is not the same as printing it. If you want to use your function as is, you would need to do:

`console.log(sleepCheck(n))`

Or, instead of returning within your function, you could just do `console.log`